# WCF Service с множеством ServiceContract (компоновка)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть WCF Service который общается с БД, в которой у меня 36 таблиц, соответственно на каждую таблицу у меня отдельный ServiceContract в котором 4 операции (Выборка, Добавление, Обновление, Удаление) и под каждый интерфейс у меня отдельный класс  который реализует этот интерфейс, но вопрос в том что по такой логике мне сейчас нужно создать один класс который будет наследоваться от 36 интерфейсов и там получится каша, а не класс, как это все можно красиво скомпоновать чтобы все не было в одном классе?

Comment: Можно сделать один сервис, у которого переопределить через ServiceBehavior параметры InstanceProvider и InstanceContextProvider для каждой конечной точки.

Comment: А уже на стороне InstanceProvider можно создавать любые классы.

Comment: А можно какой-то пример?

Comment: Его долго составлять, не раньше субботы.

Comment: Хорошо, могу подождать до субботы) спасибо заранее)))

Comment: Добрый вечер @pavel-mayorov, хотел узнать по поводу примера?